# Activating livemode for stripe parse ios app

Tags: ios, parse-platform, stripe-payments, secret-key

I've got my objective C app working in test mode for Stripe payments.  But now I'm testing it on testflight and want to take real credit card numbers.  I've swapped in the pk_live key (though I'm unsure where/if I need to update my sk_live secret key).

I'm testing the app with a real credit card to test that the payments are being charged but keep getting Parse Error 141.  I think the issue is related to the app still responding as if it's in testmode.  How to I trigger it to respond in livemode?

I'm using Parse backend.
I've manually put Stripe into "Live" mode from my web dashboard.

Thanks

This is what is happening at Stripe:

"id": "ch_161iHxblahblahblah",
  "object": "charge",
  "created": 1431455974,
  "livemode": false,
  "paid": false,
  "status": "failed",
  "amount": 300,
  "currency": "usd",
  "refunded": false,
  "source": {
    "id": "card_161iHxblahblahblah",
    "object": "card",
    "last4": "1234",
    "brand": "Visa",
    "funding": "credit",
    "exp_month": 10,
    "exp_year": 2018,
    "country": "US",
    "name": null,
    "address_line1": null,
    "address_line2": null,
    "address_city": null,
    "address_state": null,
    "address_zip": null,
    "address_country": null,
    "cvc_check": "pass",
    "address_line1_check": null,
    "address_zip_check": null,
    "dynamic_last4": null,
    "metadata": {
    },
    "customer": null
  },
  "captured": false,
  "balance_transaction": "txn_162I2Rblahblahblah",
  "failure_message": "Your card was declined. Your request was in test mode, but used a non test card. For a list of valid test cards, visit: https://stripe.com/docs/testing.",
  "failure_code": "card_declined",
  "amount_refunded": 0,
  "customer": null,
  "invoice": null,
  "description": "Charge for test@example.com",
  "dispute": null,
  "metadata": {
  },
  "statement_descriptor": null,
  "fraud_details": {
  },
  "receipt_email": null,
  "receipt_number": null,
  "shipping": null,
  "application_fee": null,
  "refunds": {
    "object": "list",
    "total_count": 0,
    "has_more": false,
    "url": "/v1/charges/ch_161iHxblahblahblah/refunds",
    "data": [

```
]
```

}
}

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this... seems very silly now but in case anyone else gets stuck at this basic step:

The secret key goes in the main.js file that you access or create via Parse Cloud Code. https://parse.com/apps/quickstart#cloud_code

Go to your Parse dashboard, then Core, then Cloud Code to confirm that you have deployed it.

Comment: Hey user2985200, I've been struggling to get the Stripe / Parse code to work for a few days now. Would you mind posting your iOS code and then your main.js code on this thread to help me (and others) out? I'm currently using this link but I keep getting an Error =\  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29538100/issues-while-integrating-stripe-with-parse/29602720#29602720